# Emma is not creating the coverage.ec file

Tags: tomcat, code-coverage, emma

Copied the emma.jar to `$JAVA_HOME/lib/ext` & instrumented it using the following command.

`java -cp emma.jar emma instr -m overwrite -cp @jarlist.txt`

jarlist.txt contains the list of jar files deployed by tomcat from the war file. And it got instrumented successfully & created the coverage.em

> > EMMA: processing instrumentation path ...
> >
> > EMMA: instrumentation path processed in 5119 ms
> >
> > EMMA: [4125 class(es) instrumented, 3142 resource(s) copied]
> >
> > EMMA: metadata merged into [/root/install/apache-tomcat-7.0.19/webapps/coverage.em] {in 553 ms}

But even after restarting the tomcat multiple times coverage.ec file was not created. What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I copied the emma.jar inside the $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/myapplication/WEB-INF/lib & then instrumenting emma resolved this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can Search the `coverage.ec` in tomcat log after stopping the Tomcat service.

it will appear in log in the End of log with the Specified Path.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the below steps:

1. Copied the emma.jar into \jre\lib\ext folder
2. Created jarlist.txt manually with the list of jar files i want to instrument.

example:

Jar names with the full path:

e:\driven\web\web-inf\lib\abc.jar
e:\driven\web\web-inf\lib\xyz.jar

Placed the jarlist.txt in the same folder - jre\lib\ext folder

1. Instrumented JARS using the Following command:

c:\Program files\java\jre\lib\ext> *java -cp emma.jar emma  instr -m overwrite -cp     @jarlist.txt*

Result: 
EMMA: processing instrumentation path ...
EMMA: instrumentation path processed in 3819 ms
EMMA: [1942 class(es) instrumented, 1030 resource(s) copied]
EMMA: metadata merged into [\jre\lib\ext\coverage.em]  {in 668 ms}

Second time if you try with the same command you will get only the following result:

EMMA: processing instrumentation path ...
EMMA: instrumentation path processed in 1875 ms
EMMA: [0 class(es) instrumented, 2972 resource(s) copied]
EMMA: no output created: metadata is empty

Because jars already instrumented --> 0 classes and no output created.

--> Start your Tomcat and Perform some operations

Tomcat Log you can find like below:
 EMMA: collecting runtime coverage data ...

If u can find this means you will get coverage.ec file while stopping the Tomcat service.

Stop the Tomcat Service: Final phase of log will show like below:

EMMA: runtime coverage data merged into [\tomcat\bin\coverage.ec] {in 48 ms}

Report Generation:

c:\jre\lib\ext>*java -cp emma.jar emma report -r html -in coverage.em,......\tomcat\bin\coverage.ec*

EMMA: processing input files ...
EMMA: 2 file(s) read and merged in 582 ms
EMMA: writing [html] report to [c:\jre\lib\ext\coverage\index.html] ...

You can Open and view the Index.html to see the Report.